# Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to add service details for a vehicle. On the show page for my vehicle I've put a button which links to add new service details

```
<%= link_to 'Add Service Details', {:controller => :services, :action => :new, :vehicle_id => @vehicle.id},  {class: "btn btn-secondary"} %>
```

The url will show the vehicle_id like the following
http://localhost:3000/services/new?vehicle_id=3

on the _form.html.erb for services I've got

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :vehicle_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :vehicle_id, id: :service_vehicle_id %>
 </div>
```

In the controller I've got

```
 def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    @service = @vehicle.service.create(service_params)
    redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' 
 end
```

and

```
def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    @service = Service.new
end
```

In my model I've defined the relationship as

Vehicle model

```
has_many :service
```

Service model

```
belongs_to :vehicle
```

My routes file looks like

```
  resources :vehicles 
  resources :services
```

Can someone please help me use the vehicle_id and save it as a foreign key. I'm not sure if the above is the right approach but I'd like it so when the user views a vehicle they've got a button which allows them to add service details.

Comment: `has_many :serviceS` in the Vehicle model, at first. And `@service = @vehicle.serviceS.create(service_params)` in the create action. And you don't need `vehicle_id` in the form

Comment: please show the params you received and the service_params method

Comment: Hi Pablo, how do I do that?

Comment: @MAhmed, look at your server logs

Comment: @Vasilisa I've made the changes getting the same error

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ISF6jFHdwxfSrXzLX+RlTrbU2Cs4gh0iEDVUtb2CBj3MCr5AEYmGLdhPYThgoDVcjb85cEX3iRfnupGFo+7f8g==",
 "service"=>
  {"servicedate(1i)"=>"2018", "servicedate(2i)"=>"3", "servicedate(3i)"=>"3", "nextservice(1i)"=>"2018", "nextservice(2i)"=>"3", "nextservice(3i)"=>"3", "description"=>"aa", "vehicle_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Service"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user go to
http://localhost:3000/services/new?vehicle_id=3
in your controller the following code run

```
def new
    #Serch for a vehicle
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    # Create a Service object with no vehicle_id set
    @service = Service.new
end
```

Like vehicle_id is not set then

```
<%= form.text_field :vehicle_id, id: :service_vehicle_id %>
```

should genarate a text field without value, when you submit the form

```
 def create
    # Here must throw an error 
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    @service = @vehicle.service.create(service_params)
    redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' 
 end
```

Go to the new action set the vehicle id

```
def new
    #Serch for a vehicle
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    # Create a Service object with no vehicle_id set
    @service = Service.new
    # Add vehicle id to service
    @service.vehicle_id = @vehicle.id
end
```

Comment: That's partly got it working. The vehicle_id is now showing but when I click save I'm still getting Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=   Its picking out @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id]) as being the issue

Comment: Thanks i got this working in the end. I had to change the create bit in the service controller to 
`def create`
  `# @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])`
    `@service = Service.new(service_params)`

    `if @service.save`
      `redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.'`
    `else`
      `render :new`
   `end`
 `end`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a form that you can place on show action of a vehicule to create a new service than what you want is just your run of the mill [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :vehicules do
  resources :services, shallow: true
end
```

This will setup the routes so that you create a new service by POST'ing to `/vehicules/:vehicule_id/services`. Note that this puts the parent id in the path so that you don't need to send it as a hidden input.

For the form you just do:

```
<%= form_for([@vehicule, @service || Service.new]) do |f| %>
  # inputs go here
<% end %>

# or with Rails 5 'form_with'
# form_with(model: @vehicule, url: [@vehicule, @service || Service.new])
```

You then setup the controller:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_vehicule, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  def new
    @service = @vehicule.services.new
  end

  def create
    @service = @vehicule.services.new(service_params)
    if @service.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  def index
    @services = @vehicule.services
  end

  # ...

  private

    def set_vehicule
      @vehicule = Vehicule.find(params[:vehicule_id])
    end

    def service_params
      # ...
    end
end
```

Comment: This answer assumes that you first fix the pluralization error in your association as pointed out by @Vasilisa.